# Xlwings: connect to Excel that is busy with calculation

Tags: python, xlwings

I need to find which of the open Excel instances have a particular file open. This is easy to do with xlwings unless some of those Excel instances are stuck in a heavy calculation. In that case xlwings will itself be stuck for a long period until it raises an exception. I'm happy to skip those instances but I don't see a way to query the busy state. Does xlwings provide a way to determine if an App is busy, or skip those apps, or set a shorter timeout period?